# I want to remove a className after a few seconds, or re trigger the class animation when condition is met

Tags: css, reactjs

**Goal**: When there is a price change,i want the price number to higlight for a few seconds with a color. I do that with the toogleClassName.

**Problem:** When the iteration is UP UP,or DOWN DOWN,the element already has that class and the CSS animation already ran.

JSX Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./CoinContainer.module.css";

function usePrevious(data) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = data;
  }, [data]);
  return ref.current;
}
export default function CoinContainer({ coin, price }) {
  const [priceUpdated, setPrice] = useState("");

  const prevPrice = usePrevious(priceUpdated);

  // Update price
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(priceUpdate, 20000);
  }, []);

  // Apply different flash-color style according to up$ or down$ from prev
  const toggleClassName = () => {
    return prevPrice > priceUpdated ? styles.redPrice : styles.greenPrice;
  };

  function priceUpdate() {
    return fetch(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coin}&vs_currencies=usd`
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((result) => {
        let key = Object.keys(result);
        setPrice(result[key].usd);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.padding}>
      <h2>{coin}</h2>
      {/* Here is the problem,i would like to remove the class after a few seconds,or edit the CSS code to retrigger the animation */}
      <h3 className={toggleClassName()}>
        {priceUpdated ? priceUpdated : price}$
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS Code

```
@keyframes upFadeBetween {
  from {
    color: green;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes downFadeBetween {
  from {
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

.redPrice {
  animation: downFadeBetween 5s;
  color: white;
}

.greenPrice {
  animation: upFadeBetween 5s;
  color: white;
}
```

Thanks so much for any feedback/help!

Comment: You could listen for animationend and remove the class(es) then so they are set afresh on the price update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another variable called e.g. `reset`

`const [reset, setReset] = useState(false);`

And then set this value at your methods using `setTimeout`

```
  const toggleClassName = () => {
    setTimeout(() => setReset(true), 6000);
    return prevPrice > priceUpdated ? styles.redPrice : styles.greenPrice;
  };


  function priceUpdate() {
    return fetch(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coin}&vs_currencies=usd`
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((result) => {
        let key = Object.keys(result);
        setReset(false);
        setPrice(result[key].usd);
      });
  }
```

and finally

```
<h3 className={reset ? "" : toggleClassName()}>
```

Comment: Thanks Apostolos. It almost works,but then if there was no price change on the priceUpdate interval, it applys the toggleClassName and runs the animation. Its closer than before tho,and can maybe make it work good with adjustments.

Comment: so then you need to enhance the method: `return prevPrice > priceUpdated ? styles.redPrice : (prevPrice < priceUpdated ? styles.greenPrice : null);`

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much Apostolos. Beast

Comment: please accept my answer in order for the question to be "closed". green tick :)

Comment: Only thing,is that on 1st interval,prevPrice is undefined and it triggers the class. I tried to do this,but no luck:

`return prevPrice > priceUpdated
      ? styles.redPrice
      : prevPrice < priceUpdated
      ? styles.greenPrice
      : !prevPrice
      ? null
      : null;
`
Your parenthesis () prettier extension took em out and works still

Comment: try this `return prevPrice && prevPrice > priceUpdated ? styles.redPrice : (prevPrice && prevPrice < priceUpdated ? styles.greenPrice : null);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

`handleClick = event => event.target.classList.add('click-state');`

or as react is js library so definitly it will support js DOM elements, well there is no doubt that it uses DOM also.
so you can do this also,

for adding class

`document.getElementById("id here").classList.add("classname here");`

for removing class

`document.getElementById("id here").classList.remove("classname here");`

OR

you can also use react States

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that will be updated every time you trigger the fetch.
In this case, we will call it **animationStyle**

```
function CoinContainer({ coin, price }) {
   const [priceUpdated, setPrice] = useState("")
   const [animationStyle, setAnimationStyle] = useState("")

   useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(priceUpdate, 20000)
   }, [])

   function updateAnimationStyle(){
      if (prevPrice > priceUpdated) {
         setAnimationStyle("redPrice")
      } else {
         setAnimationStyle("greenPrice")
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
         setAnimation("")
      }, 5000)
   }

   function priceUpdate() {
      return fetch(
         `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coin}&vs_currencies=usd`
      )
         .then((data) => data.json())
         .then((result) => {
            let key = Object.keys(result)
            setPrice(result[key].usd)
            updateAnimationStyle()
         })
   }
   return (
      <div className={styles.padding}>
         <h2>{coin}</h2>         
         <h3 className={animationStyle}>//you avoid doing the conditional rendering that might be a bit confusing
            {priceUpdated ? priceUpdated : price}$
         </h3>
      </div>
   )
}
```

1. Okay, so basically, the approach is to avoid too large conditional rendering inside the jsx.
2. the function updateAnimationStyle gets called every time the fetch is triggered.
3. depending on the condition, updateAnimationStyle will set redPrice or greenPrice animations to animationStyle.
4. the animationStyle will clean after 5 seconds through setTimeout function. "it can not be less than 5s because you have set the animation duration to 5s".
5. `const [priceUpdated, setPrice] = useState("")` it is better to avoid this type of naming for variables.
6. Instead, if you use `const [priceUpdated, setPriceUpdated] = useState("")`, it will be more readable.

Hope it works for you!
Regards.